# ¿Como puedo asignar un evento JavaScript a todos los elementos de la página exceptuando uno?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito hacer que todos los elementos de una página, al darles click, ejecuten una función, pero al mismo tiempo necesito excluir un elemento especifico incluyendo sus elementos hijos, ya que al darles click no deberían ejecutar la función antes mencionada.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto lo podrías realizar generando un evento para todo el DOM completo y después anulando los clicks que hagan sobre el elemento en cuestión utilizando `event.stopPropagation()`.

Si te fijas, en cualquier elemento que haya fuera del div `#noHagasNada` aparecerá un mensaje si haces click. Sin embargo, no hará nada si clickas sobre el div `#noHagasNada` ni sobre ninguno de sus elementos hijos.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert("hola");
}, false);
```

```css
#noHagasNada{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>Dale click</button>

<div id="noHagasNada" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
  <button>Dale click</button>
  <button>Dale click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, evidentemente esta fue la solución para mi problema, ya el código me funciona correctamente !! :D

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Me alegro mucho :) Por favor, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha resuelto tu problema. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector de esta manera:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('body *:not(.foo)').on('click', function(){
    
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.foo {
  background: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Incluido</div>
  <div>Incluido</div>  
  <div>Incluido</div>  
  <div class="foo">Excluido</div>
  <div>Incluido</div>
  <div>Incluido</div>  
  <div>Incluido</div>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Especificas el elemento que no quieras que se incluya.

Comment: No hace falta usar una clase antes del `not` puedes usar un asterisco que selecciona todos los elementos: `*:not(#excluido)`.

Comment: @rnd - Tendrías que usarlo de esta manera: `'body *:not(.bar)'` si no no funciona correctamente