# ¿Como hago para que no se cierre dentro del contenedor?

Tags: jquery, css

**EDITO LA PREGUNTA PARA QUE QUEDE CLARA.**  Me expresé fatal y mezclé varias preguntas.

**Pregunta 1**

Buenas, ¿como puedo hacer para que solo se cierre, al clicar fuera (o en el botón) y que todo vuelva a su estado original, por ejemplo que el borde vuelva tener 1px de grosor?

**Pregunta 2** (solucionada, gracias a las respuestas de abajo de @Jordifreek y @lois6b♦, básicamente que no debía centrar el click en todo el contenedor, debería hacerlo en un botón, enlace... (mirar la de @Jordifreek)).

Ahora mismo al clicar en cualquier punto del contenedor se cierra, y eso es un problema por ejemplo al querer buscar, o los checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.Enfoque-General').click(function() {
    $('.Enfoque-General-Extendido').fadeToggle(50);
    $('.Enfoque-General').css("border", "2px solid");
    $('.icon-keyboard_arrow_down').css("display", "none");
    $('.icon-keyboard_arrow_up').css("display", "block");
  });

});
```

```css
#Descripcion-Entreno {
  color: grey;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

.Enfoque-General {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0.1px solid;
  border-color: #21211d;
}

.Enfoque-General:hover {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.icon-keyboard_arrow_down {
  float: right;
}

.icon-keyboard_arrow_up {
  float: right;
  display: none;
}

.Enfoque-General-Extendido {
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.Enfoque-General-Extendido input {
  margin: 3px;
}

.Buscar-Filtros-Entreno {
  height: auto;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: grey;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

#Btn-Cerrar {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #21211d;
}

#Btn-Cerrar:hover {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Contenido">
  <h1> Generador de rutinas </h1>

  <p id="Descripcion-Entreno">
    En este apartado podrás crear rutinas, conocer músculos implicados.
  </p>

  <div class="Enfoque-General">
    Enfoque general
    <span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_down"></span>
    <span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_up"></span>

    <div class="Enfoque-General-Extendido">
      <input type="text" class="Buscar-Filtros-Entreno" placeholder="Buscar"> <span class="icon-search"></span> <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Weider <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Push / Pull <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Calistenia <br>

      <input type="button" id="Btn-Cerrar" value="Cerrar">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Carlos. Alguna de las respuestas te ha servido? Un saludo

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como puedo asignar un evento JavaScript a todos los elementos de la página exceptuando uno?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36413/como-puedo-asignar-un-evento-javascript-a-todos-los-elementos-de-la-p%c3%a1gina-exce)

Comment: Con la referencia anterior, puedes hacer que en cualquier lado de la pantalla en el que hagan clic se cierre el div exceptuando cuando hagan clic dentro del propio div.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero desde mi punto de vista no es un duplicado, pero intentaré trabajar con esa idea a ver si lo arreglo. Y en todo caso, si consideras que deba modificar algo del post o borrarlo pues lo haría sin problemas

Comment: @CarlosMilles No, es mejor no borrar los post porque, aunque sean similares, casi nunca van a ser iguales y de esta manera, si finalmente se marcara como un duplicado, los usuarios podrían ver ambos puntos de vista. Si tienes cualquier duda con el ejemplo en la otra pregunta no dudes en preguntar ;)

Comment: Ahhh vale. lo entendí mal (y el otro usuario que respondió tambien) luego la edito. @FranciscoRomero ahora si veo lo que tu dices hahah  Gracias

Comment: @lois6b Normal que la entendierais mal, porque me expresé fatal. ¡¡Muchisimas gracias por estar tan encima!!

Comment: Fascilmente puedes resolver tu situacion usando la delegacion de eventos

Answer (score 2):

Para diferenciar donde haces click, en la funcion puedes pasar el parametro `e` del evento click.

Dentro puedes poner una condicion para que si el `id` de donde has hecho click es el del contendor, que haga el Toggle.

Le puse al contenedor el id "contenedor", por ejemplo.

```
$('.Enfoque-General').click(function(e) {

    if (e.target.id == "contenedor") {
    ...
```

---

Para que vuelva a tener 1px de grosor, puse una comprobacion **antes** de que haga el toggle. Si el `.Enfoque-General-Extendido` está con `display:none`, oculto, entonces que lo ponga a tamaño 2px. Y si no está a `none` que ponga 1px.

```
if ($(".Enfoque-General-Extendido").css("display") == "none")
    $('.Enfoque-General').css("border", "2px solid");
  else
    $('.Enfoque-General').css("border", "1px solid");
```

---

**Notas:**

- A tu evento `hover` has de poner `!important;` al final para que cuando cambie el grosor , el evento siga aplicandose.

  ```
  .Enfoque-General:hover {
      border: 2px solid !important;
  }
  ```
- También añadi el evento Click al boton de "Cerrar" para que lo cierre si haces click en él

  ```
    $('#Btn-Cerrar').click(function() {
        $('.Enfoque-General-Extendido').fadeToggle(50);
    });
  ```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.Enfoque-General').click(function(e) {

    if (e.target.id == "contenedor") {
      if ($(".Enfoque-General-Extendido").css("display") == "none")
        $('.Enfoque-General').css("border", "2px solid");
      else
        $('.Enfoque-General').css("border", "1px solid");
        
      $('.Enfoque-General-Extendido').fadeToggle(50);

      $('.icon-keyboard_arrow_down').css("display", "none");
      $('.icon-keyboard_arrow_up').css("display", "block");
    }
  });
  
  $('#Btn-Cerrar').click(function() {
    $('.Enfoque-General-Extendido').fadeToggle(50);
  });

});
```

```css
#Descripcion-Entreno {
  color: grey;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

.Enfoque-General {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0.1px solid;
  border-color: #21211d;
}

.Enfoque-General:hover {
  border: 2px solid !important;
}

.icon-keyboard_arrow_down {
  float: right;
}

.icon-keyboard_arrow_up {
  float: right;
  display: none;
}

.Enfoque-General-Extendido {
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.Enfoque-General-Extendido input {
  margin: 3px;
}

.Buscar-Filtros-Entreno {
  height: auto;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: grey;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

#Btn-Cerrar {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #21211d;
}

#Btn-Cerrar:hover {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Contenido">
  <h1> Generador de rutinas </h1>

  <p id="Descripcion-Entreno">
    En este apartado podrás crear rutinas, conocer músculos implicados.
  </p>

  <div class="Enfoque-General" id="contenedor">
    Enfoque general
    <span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_down"></span>
    <span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_up"></span>

    <div class="Enfoque-General-Extendido">
      <input type="text" class="Buscar-Filtros-Entreno" placeholder="Buscar"> <span class="icon-search"></span> <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Weider <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Push / Pull <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Calistenia <br>

      <input type="button" id="Btn-Cerrar" value="Cerrar">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

El evento click no debería estar en el elemento DIV.Enfoque-General si no en un botón dentro de él que podría ser el texto "Enfoque general":

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-enfoque-general').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // evitamos que el href="#" mueva el scroll del navegaodr
    $('.Enfoque-General-Extendido').fadeToggle(50);
    $('.Enfoque-General').css("border", "2px solid");
    $('.icon-keyboard_arrow_down').css("display", "none");
    $('.icon-keyboard_arrow_up').css("display", "block");
  });

  $('#Btn-Cerrar').click(function () {
    $('.Enfoque-General-Extendido').fadeOut(50)
  });
});
```

```css
#Descripcion-Entreno {
  color: grey;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}

.Enfoque-General {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0.1px solid;
  border-color: #21211d;
}

.Enfoque-General:hover {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.icon-keyboard_arrow_down {
  float: right;
}

.icon-keyboard_arrow_up {
  float: right;
  display: none;
}

.Enfoque-General-Extendido {
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.Enfoque-General-Extendido input {
  margin: 3px;
}

.Buscar-Filtros-Entreno {
  height: auto;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: grey;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

#Btn-Cerrar {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #21211d;
}

#Btn-Cerrar:hover {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Contenido">
  <h1> Generador de rutinas </h1>

  <p id="Descripcion-Entreno">
    En este apartado podrás crear rutinas, conocer músculos implicados.
  </p>

  <div class="Enfoque-General">
    <a href="#" class="toggle-enfoque-general">Enfoque general</a>
    <span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_down"></span>
    <span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_up"></span>

    <div class="Enfoque-General-Extendido">
      <input type="text" class="Buscar-Filtros-Entreno" placeholder="Buscar"> <span class="icon-search"></span> <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Weider <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Push / Pull <br>
      <input type="checkbox"> Calistenia <br>

      <input type="button" id="Btn-Cerrar" value="Cerrar">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```